# c# new thread from timer handle issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, handle

Im experimenting with the following code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread nT = new Thread(new ThreadStart (checkThread));
        nT.Start();


    }
```

The cheackThread() function carries out a web-request and the timer's tick property is 2000ms. All objects in the checkThread() are disposed of after use. When the program is run for long periods e.g 3 hours the OS complains about low resources. I notices that in ctrl-alt-delete the handle count is increasing when the app runs. Does the thread not release its memory automatically once it has executed all its code or is this one of those times gc.collect is permitted?

Comment: Does the `checkThread` method exit gracefully, i.e. it always releases its resources?

Comment: I dispose objects used in the checkThread method such as : 
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                dataStream.Dispose();

Comment: don't use `Close()`. Put them in a `using() { }` block to be Exception-safe.

Comment: ahh yes I had thought about this but forgot to try it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the Framework handle the threads, instead of using `Thread` go for [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

> the timer's tick property is 2ms

First, your timer will not honor this. The resolution is ~20 ms.

But even 20 ms is not very long for a Webrequest. If your checkThread exceeds 20ms (every now and then) then you would be starting Threads quicker than they can finish. And so they pile up. The fact that it takes a few hours makes me think this is the most likely cause.

You could use a debugger, or a simple counter `activeThreads` (use Interlocked) to diagnose this.

Using the ThreadPool or the TPL (Fx4) would solve some of your issues but you would still need to check and limit the number of simultaneous requests.

Comment: Thanks Im going to experiment with this now

Comment: actually i meant 2 seconds :O

Comment: @brux: 2 seconds sounds a lot more reasonable, but my basic argument stays. 20ms would have been for local servers.

Comment: @brux: You would have the same problem with the ThreadPool. You need a limiter. If .5 request/second is too much for the network, it can't be done. And always use using.

Comment: if i comment all code inside the timer checkThread() method and just create the thread and call thread.start() then the problem persists so the problem could not be resolved with "using" on the objects inside the checkThread()